# Takes long time to search for users in address book

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm on SharePoint 2010 using Claims authentication (Windows NTLM). When I go to the address book to search for a user, it takes a really long time to come back with any results. I only have 135 profiles. I've looked at my UPS service and all the settings look right. My search tree looks correct as well as the filter I have setup. I've done a full synch already. How should I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Those results are not returned from the UPS, but it queries the Domain Controller instead. Are there any port restrictions between any of the SharePoint servers and all Domain Controllers within the environment? Are AD Sites and Services configured properly to route the SharePoint servers to the closest Domain Controller(s)?

Comment: Thanks. I changed the domain controller and it seems to be working better now. Here is what I did. I ran "nltest /dsgetdc:my.domain.com" to get the current server I am connecting to. Then I ran "nltest /dclist:my.domain.com" to get a list of all servers I can connect to. Then pinged them with "ping servername" and picked the one with the lowest ping. I then switched to this server with "nltest /Server:mySPservername /SC_RESET:my.domain.com".

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the nearest domain controller. This can be done by adding the subnet the SharePoint server resides on via Active Directory Sites and Services (must be completed by a Domain Admin). In this tool, you add the subnet the SharePoint servers reside on, then map it to a Site. The Site will have one or more domain controllers specified within it.

Using nltest.exe is simply a temporary fix and may change if the specified DC is restarted or if the SharePoint server is restarted.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll reach out to the network admins to permanently switch the domain controller.